# Simple Javascript Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, gallery

So I'm trying to loop through this array and change an image source every few seconds. Right now I have an onload event calling a setTimeOut method which should change the image 5 seconds after the page has loaded I would think, but it is doing it instantly. What is the problem? Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ad Rotaror</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 0;
        var ads = new Array(4);
                  ads[0]='promo1.gif';
                  ads[1]='promo2.gif';
                  ads[2]='promo3.gif';
                  ads[3]='promo4.gif';
                  ads[4]='promo5.gif';

        function change()
        {
            if(i > 4)
                i = 0;

            document.images[0].src = ads[i];
            i++;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="promo1.gif" onload="setInterval(change(), 5000)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seen a lot of these today. Are you all in the same college class?

Comment: Just a note: `setTimeout` will only run once.  `setInterval` will run many times.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my script to setInterval. And yes it's an assignment I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 'change()' to 'change'. You are calling the function immediately.

Comment: as it is an assignment the explanation is that `change` represents the function and is like writing `function() {..contents of change function..}` whereas `change()` like noted, is calling the function outright.

Comment: So the SetInterval is already expecting a function as it's first parameter so there's no need to call it?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yep, in JavaScript you can pass around functions like objects.